# Chrome extension icon change issue

Tags: google-chrome-extension, popup, icons

I'm developing a Chrome extension and have a strange problem with icon change on-the-fly.

In my popup.html I have a button by clicking on which I want to change the icon of the extension in the browser. E.g. from colored one to black and white (when application is inactive).

So the function which is responsible for this:

```
    function toggleActivated(){
        localStorage.isActive = toBool(localStorage.isActive) ? false : true;
        $('#activate-disactivate span').text(toBool(localStorage.isActive) == false ? 'Включить' : 'Выключить');
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: toBool(localStorage.isActive) ? '48.png' : '48_bw.png'});
        //window.close();
     }
```

But the problem is that I want to close popup after the icon changed. If I use the `window.close()` at the end - then the icon is not changed, but if it is commented out - then the icon is changed fine.

Why is there a conflict between `chrome.browserAction.setIcon()` and `window.close()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like `chrome.browserAction.setIcon` is getting fired asynchronously but the popup is getting closed before it finishes. You could try adding a 500ms `setTimeout` before closing.

You should also file a bug report at [new.crbug.com](http://new.crbug.com).

Comment: yes, exactly it looks like this, I added   setTimeout(function(){window.close();}, 100); and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but I was having the same problem and [abraham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26406/abraham) was right when he said that `chrome.browserAction.setIcon` was being called asynchronously. But I don't think that setting a timeout is the best answer.

If you check the [setIcon documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#method-setIcon) you can see that this method takes a function callback as parameter. That's where you should call `window.close()`. Like this:

```
chrome.browserAction.setIcon({ path: icon_path }, function() {
    window.close();
});
```

UPDATE:
As [niraj.nijju](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427334/niraj-nijju) pointed in the comment below, you can pass a tabId param to the [setIcon](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#method-setIcon) function to limit the scope of the change.

Comment: but this is changing icon in all of the tabs, I want to change only on the tab where some event occurred.

Comment: get it done with tabid

chrome.browserAction.setIcon({ path: icon_path, tabid: tab_id }, function() {
    window.close();
});

Comment: Cool, glad you managed to fix it. I will update my answer to mention the tabid param.